# How can I write a Chinese Message into NDEF message by using Android's API?

Tags: android, ndef

Now,I have an Google Nexus,and Android 4.0.4 platform.how can I write a Chinese message into a
NFC card,how do I write the NDEF message and read it?

Answer (score 0):

You can write Chinese Text Records by setting the Locale to Chinese. I suggest you read [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc.html) and in the future search the Internet before asking others.

Answer (score 0):

Create an NDEF message containing one NDEF record of Well-Known Type Text (see http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc.html#well-known-text). In case of Chinese text, you would set the language field accordingly (something like "zh-cn", "zh-hk", "zh-tw" or "zh-sg", for example) and the text encoding to whatever you want you use (UTF-8 or UTF-16).